d3.js multiple relationship visual / tangled tree => collapsible ? add link to node?
I am new with d3.js and I am trying make expandable/collapsible following project:
here
The interest of this one is the multi parents relationship.
I tried to add and modify following functions:
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
} 

I also added on the node a "click" attribute pointing to the click function. It seems that object d isn't defined in the function => nothing happens.
Could someone help ?
Snippet:


const margins = {
  top: 20,
  bottom: 300,
  left: 30,
  right: 100,
};

const height = 900;
const width = 900;

const totalWidth = width + margins.left + margins.right;
const totalHeight = height + margins.top + margins.bottom;

const svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', totalWidth)
  .attr('height', totalHeight);

const graphGroup = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

const levels = [
  [{
    id: 'Chaos',
  }],
  [{
    id: 'Gaea',
    parents: ['Chaos'],
  },
    {
      id: 'Uranus',
    },
  ],
  [{
    id: 'Oceanus',
    parents: ['Gaea', 'Uranus'],
  },
    {
      id: 'Thethys',
      parents: ['Gaea', 'Uranus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Pontus',
    },
    {
      id: 'Rhea',
      parents: ['Gaea', 'Uranus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Cronus',
      parents: ['Gaea', 'Uranus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Coeus',
      parents: ['Gaea', 'Uranus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Phoebe',
      parents: ['Gaea', 'Uranus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Crius',
      parents: ['Gaea', 'Uranus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Hyperion',
      parents: ['Gaea', 'Uranus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Iapetus',
      parents: ['Gaea', 'Uranus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Thea',
      parents: ['Gaea', 'Uranus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Themis',
      parents: ['Gaea', 'Uranus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Mnemosyne',
      parents: ['Gaea', 'Uranus'],
    },
  ],
  [{
    id: 'Doris',
    parents: ['Oceanus', 'Thethys'],
  },
    {
      id: 'Neures',
      parents: ['Pontus', 'Gaea'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Dionne',
    },
    {
      id: 'Demeter',
      parents: ['Rhea', 'Cronus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Hades',
      parents: ['Rhea', 'Cronus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Hera',
      parents: ['Rhea', 'Cronus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Alcmene',
    },
    {
      id: 'Zeus',
      parents: ['Rhea', 'Cronus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Eris',
    },
    {
      id: 'Leto',
      parents: ['Coeus', 'Phoebe'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Amphitrite',
    },
    {
      id: 'Medusa',
    },
    {
      id: 'Poseidon',
      parents: ['Rhea', 'Cronus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Hestia',
      parents: ['Rhea', 'Cronus'],
    },
  ],
  [{
    id: 'Thetis',
    parents: ['Doris', 'Neures'],
  },
    {
      id: 'Peleus',
    },
    {
      id: 'Anchises',
    },
    {
      id: 'Adonis',
    },
    {
      id: 'Aphrodite',
      parents: ['Zeus', 'Dionne'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Persephone',
      parents: ['Zeus', 'Demeter'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Ares',
      parents: ['Zeus', 'Hera'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Hephaestus',
      parents: ['Zeus', 'Hera'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Hebe',
      parents: ['Zeus', 'Hera'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Hercules',
      parents: ['Zeus', 'Alcmene'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Megara',
    },
    {
      id: 'Deianira',
    },
    {
      id: 'Eileithya',
      parents: ['Zeus', 'Hera'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Ate',
      parents: ['Zeus', 'Eris'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Leda',
    },
    {
      id: 'Athena',
      parents: ['Zeus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Apollo',
      parents: ['Zeus', 'Leto'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Artemis',
      parents: ['Zeus', 'Leto'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Triton',
      parents: ['Poseidon', 'Amphitrite'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Pegasus',
      parents: ['Poseidon', 'Medusa'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Orion',
      parents: ['Poseidon'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Polyphemus',
      parents: ['Poseidon'],
    },
  ],
  [{
    id: 'Deidamia',
  },
    {
      id: 'Achilles',
      parents: ['Peleus', 'Thetis'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Creusa',
    },
    {
      id: 'Aeneas',
      parents: ['Anchises', 'Aphrodite'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Lavinia',
    },
    {
      id: 'Eros',
      parents: ['Hephaestus', 'Aphrodite'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Helen',
      parents: ['Leda', 'Zeus'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Menelaus',
    },
    {
      id: 'Polydueces',
      parents: ['Leda', 'Zeus'],
    },
  ],
  [{
    id: 'Andromache',
  },
    {
      id: 'Neoptolemus',
      parents: ['Deidamia', 'Achilles'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Aeneas(2)',
      parents: ['Creusa', 'Aeneas'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Pompilius',
      parents: ['Creusa', 'Aeneas'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Iulus',
      parents: ['Lavinia', 'Aeneas'],
    },
    {
      id: 'Hermione',
      parents: ['Helen', 'Menelaus'],
    },
  ],
];

levels.unshift([]);

// We add one pseudo node to every level to deal with parentless nodes
levels.forEach((l, i) => {
  l.forEach((n, j) => {
    n.level = i;
    if (n.parents !== undefined) {
      n.parent = n.parents[0];
    } else {
      n.parent = `pseudo-${i - 1}`;
    }
  });
  l.unshift({
    id: `pseudo-${i}`,
    parent: i > 0 ? `pseudo-${i - 1}` : "",
    level: i
  });
});

const nodes = levels.flat();
const colours = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(nodes.filter(n => n.parents)
    .map(n => n.parents.sort()
      .join("-")))
  .range(d3.schemePaired);

function getLinks(nodes) {
  return nodes
    .filter(n => n.data.parents !== undefined)
    .map(n => n.data.parents.map(p => ({
      source: nodes.find(n => n.id === p),
      target: n
    })))
    .flat();
}

const offsetPerPartner = 3;
const drawNodePath = d => {
  const radius = 5;
  // The number of partners determines the node height
  // But when a node has only one partner,
  // treat it the same as when it has zero
  const nPartners = (d.data.partners && d.data.partners.length > 1)
    ? d.data.partners.length
    : 0;

  // We want to centre each node
  const straightLineOffset = (nPartners * offsetPerPartner) / 2;

  const context = d3.path();
  context.moveTo(-radius, 0);
  context.lineTo(-radius, -straightLineOffset);
  context.arc(0, -straightLineOffset, radius, -Math.PI, 0);
  context.lineTo(radius, straightLineOffset);
  context.arc(0, straightLineOffset, radius, 0, Math.PI);
  context.closePath();

  return context + "";
};

const drawLinkCurve = (x0, y0, x1, y1, offset, radius) => {
  const context = d3.path();
  context.moveTo(x0, y0);
  context.lineTo(x1 - 2 * radius - offset, y0);

  // If there is not enough space to draw two corners, reduce the corner radius
  if (Math.abs(y0 - y1) < 2 * radius) {
    radius = Math.abs(y0 - y1) / 2;
  }

  if (y0 < y1) {
    context.arcTo(x1 - offset - radius, y0, x1 - offset - radius, y0 + radius, radius);
    context.lineTo(x1 - offset - radius, y1 - radius);
    context.arcTo(x1 - offset - radius, y1, x1 - offset, y1, radius);
  } else if (y0 > y1) {
    context.arcTo(x1 - offset - radius, y0, x1 - offset - radius, y0 - radius, radius);
    context.lineTo(x1 - offset - radius, y1 + radius);
    context.arcTo(x1 - offset - radius, y1, x1 - offset, y1, radius);
  }
  context.lineTo(x1, y1);
  return context + "";
};

const partnershipsPerLevel = {};
const getPartnershipOffset = (parent, partner) => {
  let partnershipId, level;
  if(partner !== undefined) {
    // On every level, every relationship gets its own offset. If a relationship
    // spans multiple levels, the furthest level is chosen
    level = Math.max(parent.depth, partner.level);
    if(!partnershipsPerLevel[level]) { partnershipsPerLevel[level] = []; }
    partnershipId = [parent.id, partner.id].sort().join("-");
  } else {
    level = parent.depth;
    if(!partnershipsPerLevel[level]) { partnershipsPerLevel[level] = []; }
    partnershipId = parent.id;
  }

  // Assume that the partnership already has a slot assigned
  const partnershipOffset = partnershipsPerLevel[level].indexOf(partnershipId);
  if(partnershipOffset === -1) {
    // Apparently not
    return partnershipsPerLevel[level].push(partnershipId) - 1;
  }
  return partnershipOffset;
}

const lineRadius = 10;
const offsetStep = 5;
const linkFn = link => {
  const thisParent = link.source;
  const partnerId = link.target.data.parents.find(p => p !== thisParent.id);
  const partners = thisParent.data.partners || [];

  // Let the first link start with this negative offset
  // But when a node has only one partner,
  // treat it the same as when it has zero
  const startOffset = (partners.length > 1)
    ? -(partners.length * offsetPerPartner) / 2
    : 0;

  const partner = partners.find(p => p.id === partnerId);

  // Chaos has no partner, nor Zeus with Athena
  const nthPartner = partner !== undefined
    ? partners.indexOf(partner)
    : (partners || []).length;
  const partnershipOffset = getPartnershipOffset(thisParent, partner);

  return drawLinkCurve(
    thisParent.y,
    thisParent.x + startOffset + offsetPerPartner * nthPartner,
    link.target.y,
    link.target.x,
    offsetStep * partnershipOffset,
    lineRadius
  );
};

function draw(root) {
  // Now every node has had it's position set, we can draw them now
  const nodes = root.descendants()
    .filter(n => !n.id.startsWith("pseudo-"));
  const links = getLinks(nodes)
    .filter(l => !l.source.id.startsWith("pseudo-"));

  const link = graphGroup.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links);
  link.exit().remove();
  link.enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .merge(link)
    .attr("stroke", d => colours(d.target.data.parents.sort().join("-")))
    .attr("d", linkFn);

  const node = graphGroup.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes);
  node.exit().remove();
  const newNode = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .on("click", click)
    .attr("class", "node");

  newNode.append("path")
    .attr("d", drawNodePath);
  newNode.append("text")
    .attr("dy", -3)
    .attr("x", 6);

  newNode.merge(node)
    .attr("transform", d => `translate(${d.y},${d.x})`)
    .selectAll("text")
    .text(d => d.id);
}

const root = d3.stratify()
  .parentId(d => d.parent)
  (nodes);

// Map the different sets of parents,
// assigning each parent an array of partners
getLinks(root.descendants())
  .filter(l => l.target.data.parents)
  .forEach(l => {
    const parentNames = l.target.data.parents;
    if (parentNames.length > 1) {
      const parentNodes = parentNames.map(p => nodes.find(n => n.id === p));

      parentNodes.forEach(p => {
        if (!p.partners) {
          p.partners = [];
        }
        parentNodes
          .filter(n => n !== p && !p.partners.includes(n))
          .forEach(n => {
            p.partners.push(n);
          });
      });
    }
  });

// Take nodes with more partners first,
// also counting the partners of the children
root
  .sum(d => (d.value || 0) + (d.partners || []).length)
  .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);

const tree = d3.tree()
  .size([height, width])
  .separation((a, b) => {
    // More separation between nodes with many children
    const totalPartners = (a.data.partners || []).length + (b.data.partners || []).length;
    return 1 + (totalPartners / 5);
  });

draw(tree(root));

function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
} 
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.node path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 3;
  fill: white;
}
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>




post should be fine now, thank you
